# Accessing nested array at a dynamic depth

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following piece of `json`, it follows a specific pattern but each object can have any number of `children` and each of those `children` objects can have any number of `children` ..

```
[
  {
    "name": "1st level",
    "parentId": "",
    "id": "dummyvalue1",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "2nd level child",
        "parentId": "dummyvalue1",
        "id": "dummyvalue2"
      },
      {
        "name": "another 2nd level child",
        "id": "dummyvalue3",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "3rd level child",
            "id": "dummyvalue4",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "4th level child",
                "parentId": "dummyvalue4",
                "id": "dummyvalue5"
              }
            ],
            "parentId": "dummyvalue3"
          }
        ],
        "parentId": "dummyvalue1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The problem is, I only need to access objects at a specific depth within this nested `object`/`array` structure.

And that `depth` is dynamic.

If the `depth` equals 3, then I would like to add a new dummy object into the `children` array for that level. So the new structure would look like this ..

```
[
  {
    "name": "1st level",
    "parentId": "",
    "id": "dummyvalue1",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "2nd level child",
        "parentId": "dummyvalue1",
        "id": "dummyvalue2"
      },
      {
        "name": "another 2nd level child",
        "id": "dummyvalue3",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "3rd level child",
            "id": "dummyvalue4",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "4th level child",
                "parentId": "dummyvalue4",
                "id": "dummyvalue5"
              }
            ],
            "parentId": "dummyvalue3"
          },
          {
            "name": "NEW OBJECT",
            "parentId": "dummyvalue3",
            "id": "random"
          }
        ],
        "parentId": "dummyvalue1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there a clean way to do this? Instead of huge loops trying to iterate to the right level. Also dont think I can use dot notation since the number of levels and the `depth` variable is dynamic

Comment: what if in your object `"name": "2nd level child"` there is a children property, and that path also contain 3rd level depth? you want to push the new object in both the path at level 3?

Comment: no, i would like to specify which 3rd level `children` to insert using `dummyvalue4` as an identifier for the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created this function:

```
function addChild(currentChild, childToAdd, depth) {
  if (depth === 1) {
    currentChild.children.push(childToAdd);
    return;
  }

  const nextChild = currentChild.children.filter(child => child.children && child.children.length)[0];

  if (!nextChild) {
     if (currentChild.children && currentChild.children.length) {
       currentChild.children[0].children = [childToAdd];
     } else {
       currentChild.children = [childToAdd];
     }
     return;
  }

  addChild(nextChild, childToAdd, depth - 1);
}
```

It takes 3 arguments:

1. The current child
2. The child to add
3. The remaining depth to run through

If the `depth` is 1, it simply add the `child` to the `children`. If not, it looks inside the `children`, take the first one with `children` and make a recursive call to the same function.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "name": "1st level",
    "parentId": "",
    "id": "dummyvalue1",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "2nd level child",
        "parentId": "dummyvalue1",
        "id": "dummyvalue2"
      },
      {
        "name": "another 2nd level child",
        "id": "dummyvalue3",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "3rd level child",
            "id": "dummyvalue4",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "4th level child",
                "parentId": "dummyvalue4",
                "id": "dummyvalue5"
              }
            ],
            "parentId": "dummyvalue3"
          }
        ],
        "parentId": "dummyvalue1"
      }
    ]
  }
]

function addChild(currentChild, childToAdd, depth) {
  if (depth === 1) {
    currentChild.children.push(childToAdd);
    return;
  }
  
  const nextChild = currentChild.children.filter(child => child.children && child.children.length)[0];
  
  if (!nextChild) {
     if (currentChild.children && currentChild.children.length) {
       currentChild.children[0].children = [childToAdd];
     } else {
       currentChild.children = [childToAdd];
     }
     return;
  }

  addChild(nextChild, childToAdd, depth - 1);
}

addChild(data[0], {foo: 'bar'}, 3);
addChild(data[0], {bar: 'baz'}, 2);
addChild(data[0], {baz: 'foo'}, 1);
addChild(data[0], {extraChild: 'foo'}, 4);


console.log(data);
```

Comment: It's important to note this will always add to the children of the first element of the matching depth.

Comment: Yes, I've mentioned it above the snippet.

Comment: what does this function do if I specify `depth` of 2 and the existing data structure only has 1 level of depth? i.e the `children` array at level 1 does not exist .. is it possible to create it at that point?

Comment: @bobbyrne01 I've updated my code so it adds a child to the children at the maximum depth provided if the initial depth is greater than the maximal depth of the object.

Comment: @bobbyrne01 if it's ok for you, feel free top upvote and accept my answer